# SQLite copy only numbers or letters from one column to another

Tags: sqlite, select, copy

I have some data in a SQLite table e.g.

```
111222_abc
def_333444
556789_hij
123456XY
789123ZZB
```

What I want out is a pair of columns with only the numbers and only the letters such as:

```
Col 1    Col 2 
111222   abc
333444   def
556789   hij
123456   XY
789123   ZZB
```

Tried REGEX select but it doesn't seem to work I'm only getting "1" or "0" as a result. True/False?

Comment: It might also be good to also post your "REGEX select" attempt.

Comment: UPDATE Tab1 SET ID_Base=( SELECT * FROM ID WHERE REGEX "[0-9]+";

Comment: That is probably wrong but my googleFu is lacking on this one

Comment: Sqlite only has regex support if you load the ICU extension.

Comment: Thanks Shawn; is there another way to do this without regex?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after much googling etc I ended up using Python to sort this out: con is a sqlite connection.

```
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Table')

        rows = cur.fetchall()
        n=1
        for row in rows:
#            print (row)
            ID_Init=row[1]
            ID_Check=row[2]
            if ID_Init:
                temp=""
                ID_Base=re.findall(r'\d{6}',ID_Init)
                temp=''.join(ID_Base)
                ID_Base=temp

                temp=""
                ID_Extn=re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+',ID_Init)
                temp=''.join(ID_Extn)
                ID_Extn=temp
            else:
                if ID_Check:
                    temp=""
                    ID_Base=re.findall(r'\d+',ID_Check)
                    temp=''.join(ID_Base)
                    ID_Base=temp
                else:
                    ID_Base="NONE"
                ID_Extn="NONE"

            cur.execute('''UPDATE Table SET ID_Base=?, ID_Extn=? WHERE rowid==?''',(ID_Base, ID_Extn, n)) 
            n += 1
```

This may not be the best way of doing what I want but it works and I'm happyy with the results. The initial question didn't specify; but the numbers are always in a group of 6 when they are in the correct column.

I added a second check where the numbers may be in a description column with extra characters between them.

Note: this processes through my 10,000 odd rows very quickly.